# None values after reading more than 10000 rows of .xlsx file in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm working on a application that can read out a large .xlsx (more than 20000 rows) with Openpyxl and can make some basic calculations with this data. I try to read out 20000 rows in the example below. When I run this code in the command promt of Windows the output is fine, but when I run it in a linux terminal or in the terminal of PyCharm the output after 10000 changes to None.

I already tried to change the load_workbook read_only parameter to True, but that completely destroyed the performance of the application

```
from openpyxl import *

wb = load_workbook(filename="wind_data.xlsx", read_only=False)
ws = wb.active

output_data = [ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value for i in range(2, 20002)]

for i in range(0, len(output_data)):
    print(str(i+1) + " : " + str(output_data[i]))
```

The output I expect from this code would end with:

```
19998 : 6
19999 : 6
20000 : 6
```

But instead I get:

```
19998 : None
19999 : None
20000 : None
```

Comment: Have you double-checked that the file really is identical on both computers? openpyxl does not use platform-specific code so behaviour will be the same. Also, using `ws.cell()` is your problem in read-only mode. Always use `ws.iter_rows()` for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using generator comprehension for really big collections.

```
output_data = (ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value for i in range(2, 20002))
```

This might help in your case. I test it on my linux and it's works fine on excel with over 20k rows. 
Secondly when you want to iterate thru such collection and also have indexes use function:

> enumerate(collection)

Like:

```
for i, val in enumerate(output_data):
    print('{} : {}'.format(i+1, val)
```

Comment: I tried this method but it didn't make any difference, both in PyCharm and on the linux machine. But thanks for the tips.

Comment: I ran it on both a virtual machine with Ubuntu and a laptop with Manjaro and both returned the same output. While the windows terminal ran it without issues.